# ASP.NET MVC : Displaying same results on different view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing a learning project with ASP.NET MVC.I have a page that lists logged users's books and I want to display books in two formats like this

- **Normal List** --> Display Book Thumbnail, Title,Page count,Author...
- **Detail List** ---> Display only Book Title,Author,Page Count in HTML Table format
  format

so I have two view pages Books.aspx,BookDetails.aspx. One for normal list,one for detail list but I have one controller action that returns books from database and can return results only to one page.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //get books from database
        return View(bookList);
    }
```

Do I have  to include a parameter and check parameter to return list to different view or is there a better way to do this? How can I use same Controller action to display two views?

Comment: "One for normal list,one for detail list but I have one controller action that returns books from database and can return results only to one page." <- Why is that?

Comment: Ok I can create two Controller actions one for Detail List one for Normal List but I dont want to duplicate the same code in two places

Comment: create a method that retrieves the book data and call that from each action...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using partial views and create controller actions for them

```
public ActionResult NormalList{
    ViewData["normalList"] = //db retrieval code;
    return View("NormalList");
}

public ActionResult DetailedList{
    ViewData["detailedList"] = //db retrieval code;
    return View("DetailedList");
}
```

in your page

```
<%= Html.RenderPartial("NormalList", ViewData)%>


<%= Html.RenderPartial("DetailedList", ViewData)%>
```

and in your partial

```
<%foreach(var item in (IEnumerable)ViewData["normalList"]){%>
//blah blah blah
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the view name:

```
return View("Books", bookList);
```

...or....

```
return View("BookDetails", bookList);
```